# Will my laptop work properly with high performance monitor?

Tags: laptop, monitors

I have HP EliteBook x360 1030 G7 Notebook 13" laptop. It's built-in monitor has Full HD resolution and 60Hz refreshing rate.
I'd like to buy some kind of external monitor 24" or 27" to use with it. For example [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09HH8JCRV) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WSK5W7V)
In case the external monitor will have 2K or 4K resolution or / and high refreshing rate i.e. 144Hz - will it be possible to use it with my laptop connected directly with HDMI cable?
I mean will the external monitor work in it's high resolution / high refreshing rate in this case?
In case I will need to perform some setting on the laptop to set the external monitor refreshing rate / resolution - will it be kept in case I change the external monitor? I'm working in hybrid mode - 2 days a week in the office (with some big monitor there) and 3 days at home, so I'm switching between monitors almost each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [HP's website](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c06719267), your laptop contains a HDMI 1.4b port and 2 Thunderbolt ports capable of DisplayPort 1.2. These will be the limiting factors as to which resolutions and refresh rates your laptop can run, assuming you purchase cables running at that standard or higher and the monitor supports at least that standard or higher.

[HDMI 1.4b specifications](https://www.hdmi.org/spec/hdmi1_4b) say that it can handle up to 3840×2160 at 30 Hz, and 1920×1080 at 120 Hz. However, HP's website says your laptop is capable of up to 4k (3840x2160) at up to 60 Hz using the HDMI port.

DisplayPort 1.2 should be able to handle 1920x1080 at up to 240 Hz, 2560 × 1440 at up to 165 Hz, and 3840 × 2160 at up to 75 Hz. However, at this point there are no official guidelines restricting companies from calling their DisplayPort ports whatever version they want, so there is no way to know for sure.

In conclusion, you *should* be able to run either of the monitors you linked at full resolution and refresh rate using Thunderbolt to DisplayPort or HDMI (assuming you get compatible cables).

In my experience with a similar HP laptop, I could not get 4k at 60 Hz working on HDMI, but it worked with DisplayPort over Thunderbolt. 1440p at 75 Hz worked with DisplayPort as well, but I never tried HDMI.

If you need to change refresh rates or resolutions for specific monitors, it should auto-detect and keep your settings every time you use that monitor as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt and very detailed answer! Will I need to set `Show only on 2` display in "Multiple displays" section in the Display setting of my laptop? Currently with the old external monitor supporting only Full HD / 60Hz I use `Duplicate these displays` there.

Comment: @Prophet you should be able to run both the internal and external displays at the same time. If you are only using one, though, you can choose which one to use (only 1 or 2). Duplicating displays shows the same thing on both, if that's what you want. You should be able to use any option.